# Oracle conditional where

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am trying to add conditional where, so where parameter ClientId is other then '' then it's value should be use in where, but if ClientId is = '' then where should not be applyed,

I tried with this, but this gives me empty result all the time

```
DEFINE ClientId = '123';

:
:
WHERE (('&ClientId' <> '' AND Delivery.Client.CLNT_ID = 100038324) OR ('&ClientId' = ''))
```

Comment: I don't know Oracle very well, but assuming the variable usage is correct, the logic looks fine.

Comment: Not quite ... `'' = NULL` in Oracle, hence why it's not working .. I'm writing up a solution now .. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` .. an empty string '' in Oracle is considered a `NULL` value, and `anything = NULL` is "false" ..

Try this:

```
  drop table junk;

  create table junk ( client_id   number );

  insert into junk values ( 123 );
  insert into junk values ( 234 );

  commit;

  define ClientID = '123';

  select *
    from junk
   where (('&ClientID' IS NOT NULL AND client_id = 234)
        or ('&ClientID' IS NULL))
  /

   CLIENT_ID
  ----------
         234


  define ClientID = '';

  select *
    from junk
   where (('&ClientID' IS NOT NULL AND client_id = 234)
        or ('&ClientID' IS NULL))
  /

   CLIENT_ID
  ----------
         123
         234
```

Comment: You could also play with `NVL('&ClientID',client_id)` or something .. however, you have to be careful with indexes .. it could easily confuse the optimizer ;)